# Assign to group using case tracker in drupal 6

Tags: 6

I am using Drupal 6 and meetings module and case tracker module. Individual assignment is possible. But Assignment to group i haven't got it working. Is it possible i.e. assignment to a group and each member in the group or role get a cloned item which is created.